# auto login from app in iframe

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website where a user logs in with his Facebook account. He can then invite his Friends by sending them an invite.

When a Friend opens his invitation at Facebook he'll see a website inside the Facebook canvas (iframe).

Because this friend is already logged into the real Facebook, i expected him to be automatically logged in to my website aswell. But that's not the case.

How can i auto login the friend who opens my application from the Facebook iframe??

(I'm using C# MVC3 and the JS lib)

NOTE;

I've been readin numerous topics about this problem. An answer is to use getLoginStatus(). But that's not working for me because i'm still in sandbox mode... Is there any decent work around for this?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? I also having the same issue..

Answer (score 1):

A user logged into Facebook, and then coming into your site (canvas or web app) cannot be auto-logged because this "new" visitor has never authorised your App to access to his Facebook data.

You can do an auto login for people you have a valid auth session key for this user, and for that, they need first to Connect with your Facebook App.